# Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in C:\wamp\

Tags: php, deprecated, posix-ere

please when using the eregi() function to validate an email address i got this error:

```
Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\ssiphone\classes\TraitementFormulaireContact.php on line 13
```

my code which may make problem is :

```
 public function verifierMail($mail)
 {
    if(eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $mail)) {
      return "valid mail";
    }
    else {
      return "invalid mail";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your regular expression is invalid. Use [`filter_Var()` function](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) - it's a way easier that writing your own expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `eregi` function is deprecated, which means that in future versions of PHP it will be removed.

You can replace it with the function `preg_match` which does pretty much the same thing.

Sample code (untested):

```
public function verifierMail($mail)
{
if(preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $mail)) {
  return "valid mail";
}
else {
  echo "invalid mail";
}
```

The /i makes it case insensitive

Answer (score 2):

use the function `preg_match()` instead

you can find the php manual page here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1):

Aside from substituting `ereg_*` with `preg_*`, you should consider the builtin [`filter_var()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function:

```
filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

you'll still get false negatives (there are a lot of valid emails you'd never imagine), but it's still better than a poor regexp.